# I enabled CORS, but still getting restricted

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, react-typescript

This is my configuration in asp.net core web API:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                       .AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

and

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

And finally my javascript (typescript react):

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors' as RequestMode,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ Username: username, Password: password })
};

return fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/auth/register`, requestOptions).then(res => {
    debugger;
    if (res.ok === false) {
        return Promise.reject("Invalid request");
    }

    return res.json();
});
```

I can't figure it out. I've tried changing the mode on the client-side. I've tried.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000") in the API and I'm now out of luck. What am I missing here? I ran my react app with npm start, is that it? Should not be?

Response:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44346/auth/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:44346
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The response headers:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 22:23:37 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Do you also get this error when you request something that *isn't* a 404?

Comment: What *exactly* is the cors error message?

Comment: Hello @KevinB, Thats the strange part. Im getting 204 on the OPTION call (preflight) but 404 on the POST call. Response and response headers are posted in the post

Comment: Right, but, what's actually the error? without the actual cors error, we can only speculate on why the browser is rejecting it.

Comment: Your headers appear to be in order, and your last comment seems to confirm that the preflight isn't failing, so... i suspect this might not be a cors related problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The order of middlewares is important.

In your `Configure()` method first add `app.UseRouting();` and after that `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");`

Comment: Tried it, no difference

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
  mode: 'cors' as RequestMode
```

from your javascript
and instead of

```
body: JSON.stringify({ Username: username, Password: password })
```

use

```
body: { Username: username, Password: password }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { ExpectedConditions as EC, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
// ...

async function getTextFromClipboard() {
  // ...
  await browser.wait(
    EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('.btn-copy'))),
    waitTimeout
  );
  await element(by.css('.btn-copy')).click();
}
```